# How to create dependent dropdown using VBA in Excel 2016?

Tags: vba, excel, nested, dropdown

I want to create a dropdown in the B column of the following worksheet (Planning):

[image: Planning Worksheet]

The D3 Cell contains the language to display. When a Dimension is entered in Column A, I would like a dropdown of parts filtered by the entered Dimension.

The data are contained in the following worksheet (Data):

[image: Data Worksheet]

To complicate things, I would like the dropdown to display content from the Data worksheet depending on the selected language in Planning.$D3 (If English is selected show green text, if Japanese is selected, show red text). Only the lines with a Dimension and a Label == "index" should appear in the dropdown (2, 8, 15, ...). Once selected, the dropdown should display the Part data (blue).

How can I build such a dropdown in VBA?

Comment: The dropdown menus that apprear inside a cell can only me generated using validation so you could possibly use VBA to set the validation required for each cell once you have entered a value in column A or you could use a Form that contains a dropdown list that pops up once the value in column A has been entered.  You'll need to loop throught the sheet Data to extract the Parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting problem and I got the code below to work using the method of setting validation on the cell in column B when a Dimension code is entered in column A.

The colour of the text in column B is changed to blue once an option has been selected but the Green and Red text that you wanted is not really possible as in the in-cell dropdown always displays black regardless of the cell's font colour.

The code is not perfect but more just a proof of concept and something to give you a big head start.

```
Dim CHANGING_VAL As Boolean 'Global Variable that can be set to prevent the onchange being fired when the Macro is removing the description from the dropdown.

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)


    If Target.Column = 2 And CHANGING_VAL = False Then
        CHANGING_VAL = True
        If InStr(1, Target.Value, "~") > 2 Then
            Target.Value = Left(Target.Value, InStr(1, Target.Value, "~") - 2)
        End If
        Target.Validation.Delete
        Target.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        CHANGING_VAL = False
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        If Target.Offset(0, -1) <> "" Then
            strValidList = ""
            For intRow = 1 To 300
                If Sheets("Data").Cells(intRow, 1) = Target.Offset(0, -1) Then
                    If Sheets(Target.Parent.Name).Cells(3, 4) = "English" Then
                        strValidList = strValidList & Sheets("Data").Cells(intRow, 2) & " ~ " & Sheets("Data").Cells(intRow, 3) & ", "
                    Else
                        strValidList = strValidList & Sheets("Data").Cells(intRow, 2) & " ~ " & Sheets("Data").Cells(intRow, 4) & ", "
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            If strValidList <> "" Then
                strValidList = Left(strValidList, Len(strValidList) - 2)

                Target.Select

                With Selection.Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=strValidList
                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                    .InputTitle = ""
                    .ErrorTitle = ""
                    .InputMessage = ""
                    .ErrorMessage = ""
                    .ShowInput = True
                    .ShowError = True
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Else
        Sheets(Target.Parent.Name).Range("B:B").Validation.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I might have actually not express the question well. I am not trying to change the color of the data, but create dropdowns with the colored data. I will edit my question to reflect this more accurately.